# Hibernate generates strange queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have written a simple REST app. These are the fragments from it:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Project {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Video> video = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Video {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private byte[] content;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table( name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Project> project = new HashSet<>();
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final ProjectService projectService;
    @GetMapping("/get-projects")
    public List<Project> getUserProjects() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) throw new RuntimeException("NPE"); //todo сделать нормальное исключение
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal == null || !(principal instanceof UserDetailsImpl)) throw new RuntimeException("NPE or cast exception"); //todo сделать нормальное исключение
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return projectService.findAllByUserId(user.getId());
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProjectService {

    private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    public List<Project> findAllByUserId(UUID id) {
        return projectRepository.findAllByUserId(id);
    }
}

public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, UUID> {

    @Query("select p from Project p where p.user.id = :userId")
    List<Project> findAllByUserId(UUID userId);
}
```

And this output I can see in the console:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_2_,
        user0_.email as email2_2_,
        user0_.password as password3_2_ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    where
        user0_.email=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        project0_.id as id1_0_,
        project0_.title as title2_0_,
        project0_.user_id as user_id3_0_ 
    from
        project project0_ 
    where
        project0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        user0_.email as email2_2_0_,
        user0_.password as password3_2_0_ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        video0_.project_id as project_1_1_0_,
        video0_.video_id as video_id2_1_0_,
        video1_.id as id1_4_1_,
        video1_.content as content2_4_1_ 
    from
        project_video video0_ 
    inner join
        video video1_ 
            on video0_.video_id=video1_.id 
    where
        video0_.project_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        project0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_,
        project0_.project_id as project_2_3_0_,
        project1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        project1_.title as title2_0_1_,
        project1_.user_id as user_id3_0_1_,
        user2_.id as id1_2_2_,
        user2_.email as email2_2_2_,
        user2_.password as password3_2_2_ 
    from
        users_project project0_ 
    inner join
        project project1_ 
            on project0_.project_id=project1_.id 
    left outer join
        users user2_ 
            on project1_.user_id=user2_.id 
    where
        project0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        video0_.project_id as project_1_1_0_,
        video0_.video_id as video_id2_1_0_,
        video1_.id as id1_4_1_,
        video1_.content as content2_4_1_ 
    from
        project_video video0_ 
    inner join
        video video1_ 
            on video0_.video_id=video1_.id 
    where
        video0_.project_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        video0_.project_id as project_1_1_0_,
        video0_.video_id as video_id2_1_0_,
        video1_.id as id1_4_1_,
        video1_.content as content2_4_1_ 
    from
        project_video video0_ 
    inner join
        video video1_ 
            on video0_.video_id=video1_.id 
    where
        video0_.project_id=?
```

I understand where the first three queries are from. They are from the Spring Security and working of the Repository. But origin of the other queries is mystery for me. Please help me to understand.

Comment: The first 3 are not Spring security, likely just the first is. The second one is your own findAllByUserId query. Everything after that is also likely related to building Project instances - it seems to fetch a whole lot of data, and some of those have eager relationships to other entities, which Hibernate uses joins for. Turn on parameter logging for proof, and check your entity graph and you'll be able to explain the queries. I suspect the first is to build the project, and the others are when you serialize the instance and that your serialization process is walking the graph

Comment: I think you should try to map a dto not entity it printed all of related entities. that is why you can see some several queries